# After installing the magento 2.3 backend not work

Tags: magento2

After magento2.3 installing it give me error .Can any one help me thank you in advance

Error:
This page isn’t working .redirected you too many times.

Answer (score 1):

Go in the app/etc/di.xml

Search below line

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
```

Replace that with below line and check

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

Also Run the below CLI command:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this step and check

```
rm -rf pub/static var/cache var/composer_home var/generation var/page_cache var/view_preprocessed

Run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```